# inner join en inicio de sesion ¿es posible?

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero hacer un `inner join` al momento de iniciar sesion para que todo se guarde en una sola variable y asi poderla usar en muchas partes que se require

¿como puedo generarla?

mi `Query` de `MySQL` es asi

```
   $statement = $conexion->prepare('
        SELECT usuarios.email, usuarios.password, usuarios.nombre, usuarios.apellidos, 
        perfusu.profesion, perfusu.universidad, perfusu.ciudad, perfusu.puesto, perfusu.empresa, 
        perfusu.responsabilidades, perfusu.habilidades, perfusu.extra, perfusu.thumb 
        FROM usuarios INNER JOIN perfusu ON usuarios.idUsuario = perfusu.idUsuario 
        WHERE usuarios.email = :email AND usuarios.password = :password'
    );
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':email' => $email,
        ':password' => $password
    ));

    $resultado = $statement->fetch();
    if ($resultado !== false) {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $resultado;
        header('Location: ' . RUTA . '/index.php');
    } else {
        $errores .= '<li>Datos Incorrectos</li>';
    }
```

mi tabla de perfil tiene relacion con la tabla de usuario como se puede observar pero solo la tabla de usuarios tiene el email, password, nombre y apellidos

Comment: Y cual es el problema exactamente? Veo el inner ya hecho. Que es lo que te pasa realmente? No termino de entender la pregunta. Respecto si es posible pues si , si es posible.

Comment: @Xerif que tal, al momento de hacer toda la relacion y el select, al momento de dar submit en el login no me deja entrar ya que me marca que los datos son incorrectos.

Comment: Probaste la consulta directamente en el SGBD que tengas?

Comment: cierto, ya encontre el error